# Is it possible to create a form post wordpress custom navigation link?

Tags: posts, forms, navigation

I work with a church that has a donate button on their site. The button uses a form post to connect with their simple checkout item and they want a button on the navigation to link to the donation page as well.

[image: navigation linke]

How do I create this link that will do this, is this possible? Or will I need to create a static button?

Answer (score 1):

if you login to the WordPress admin area. You will see under the appearance menu a link that says "Menus". Click that and on the left side, there will be a little panel that says

"Custom Links"

give it the url of the page that you want and a name in the label field and save it and add it to your menu. Make sure you save all changes when doing so. This will add the link to the navigation

Comment: Thanks for responding, my issue is not creating a custom link. I was trying to see if I could send data in a single url and nota form..I dont think its possible

Answer (score 0):

I too wanted to do something similar.  I found a plugin called JinMenu that allows you to add onClick code to your menu items.

On our page, we have a form with the attribute `name="_xclick"`.

After installing the plugin, I was able to add this to my onClick event:

```
document.forms['_xclick'].submit(); return false;
```

That triggers my form when the menu item is clicked.

The only catch is that you must have this form on every page; otherwise your link will fail when clicked.  I hope this helps you and/or others who are looking for this.

Comment: Please explain exactly how this relates to the question asked.